# Do not call the method if the service is not registered

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

My method should not call ApplyAsync() if the service is not registered. I'm trying to add a conditional null, but I still get a null reference at the moment the method is called. Am I doing something wrong?

```
private static async Task ApplyMigrationsAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        using var scope = Startup.ServiceProvider.CreateScope();
        var migration = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<M.Migrations.IMigration>();
        await migration?.ApplyAsync(token);
    }
```

Comment: [Do not post images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying conditionala access `?` and awaiting the result will end in awaiting `null`. Which cannot be awaited.

Guard your access with an `if` statement and await inside the `if` block:

```cs
private static async Task ApplyMigrationsAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        using var scope = Startup.ServiceProvider.CreateScope();
        var migration = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<M.Migrations.IMigration>();
        if (migration != null) 
        {
            await migration.ApplyAsync(token);
        }
    }
```